# Coldfusion Parse URLs in text

Tags: regex, coldfusion

Can anyone help with a function that will parse all urls into valid html links in a text string?

For example:

"Welcome to `www.nerds4life.com`. View our articles at `nerds4life.com` or at `http://nerds4life.com` or also `http://www.nerds4life.com`"

would become:

"Welcome to [www.nerds4life.com](http://www.nerds4life.com). View our articles at [nerds4life.com](http://nerds4life.com) or at http://nerds4life.com or also http://www.nerds4life.com"

What would be the best way to approach this. Regex (and if so, how?) or loop through each word in the text (would think that's less efficient)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again... there may be a more elegant regex...

Certainly feel free to google for "good" regex's for finding URLs if this one falls short.

```
<cfset myText = "Welcome to www.nerds4life.com. View our articles at nerds4life.com or at http://nerds4life.com or also http://www.nerds4life.com or at https://foo.com or http://123.com" />

<cfset myNewText = rereplaceNoCase( myText, '((http(s)?://)?((www\.)?\w+\.\w{2,6}))', '<a href="http://\4">\1</a>', 'all' ) />
```

Comment: Hi again Charlie. Again, this is doing the trick for every test case so far, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will parse URL in string that starts with http or www and terminated by a space

```
<cfset myString = "Welcome to www.nerds4life.com. View our articles at nerds4life.com or at http://nerds4life.com or also http://www.nerds4life.com">
<cfset URLinString = rereplaceNoCase(myString, '(((http(s)?://)|(www))\.?(\S+))', '<a href="http://\1">\1</a>', 'all')>
```